# Is there a way to update OpenSSH for Windows to the latest version?

Tags: git, bash, upgrade, openssh

Git Bash comes installed with a pretty old version of OpenSSH (v 4.6p1), and I was wondering if there's a straightforward way to update it to the latest version under Windows 7?

I've searched the web far and wide, but sadly can't find anything about this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: 0.9.8e is the version of OpenSSL in git bash, not of OpenSSH. These are different components.

Comment: Also, `ControlPersist` won't bring you much speed improvement at all as git uses a single ssh connection. Thus, once the connection is established (which happens once per push), you will not gain anything.

Comment: Ah, so it is, thanks. It's using OpenSSH version 4.6p1, which is still very old. I've read elsewhere that just updating OpenSSH can yield significant improvements, so if anybody knows how to update it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked: http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That version is from 2004. The current official site is at http://www.openssh.com but even after installing it it doesn't automatically update the Git version. Manual steps are required. This site (http://darrell.mozingo.net/2011/09/29/painfully-slow-clone-speeds-with-msysgit-gitextensions/), for example outlines instructions on how to perform an OpenSSH update for Git, but it's for GitExtensions and uses Cygwin's .dll files. This results in all my paths having a cygdrive pre-fix (amongst other issues). So I was hoping someone may know of similar instructions, exclusively for Git Bash.

Comment: You'll gain performance improvements only with [HPN patches](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh) applied.  The question is: can you just update your server's setup to provide for working with Git using HTTP[S]? You won't need anything besides Apache/Nginx and stock Git for this. Authentication is another story of course...

Comment: Also see [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/msysgit/fhx6s4Y2Vpo/discussion) and search [the list](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/) for the "OpenSSH" word to get more ideas on how to approach this problem.  The basic thing is "get the GfW dev. environment, update OpenSSH to the recent version and make the whole thing build".

Comment: I was hoping for an ssh update in msysgit as well. This article states that you would get some speed improvements out of it though:
http://interrobeng.com/2013/08/25/speed-up-git-5x-to-50x/